# How frequently do accelerating electrons emit photons?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics

In the quantum 2-slit experiment with light, we know that as the source intensity is turned down, individual photons arrive at the detector.

I would like to know if there is a formula which tells us how frequently an electron (or other simple source) emits photons. It must be possible to measure this frequency, so there must be a quantum calculation which reproduces the experimental data.

I'm interested in simple cases, such as an electron accelerating in a static background field, or a Hertzian dipole. What is the frequency a function of? I guess the frequency will actually be a distribution of some sort (rather than a single number)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation

Comment: An accelerating electric charge continually produces ripples in the electric quantum field. If you want a mental picture, don't imagine a ball from which another ball separates once in a while - imagine a wake behind a boat. It's not a very accurate picture, but it's a lot better than thinking about "photons" being "emitted" from an accelerating electron.

Answer (score 0):

Both the electron and the photon are subject to quantum effects and your intuition that the answer will be a probibility distribution rather than a number  (obtained from evaluating a Feynman diagram)is correct. There is indeed a formula for this process and the answer will also depend on the details of the accelerating force.